# Where did guru Shukracharya live?

Tags: guru, shukracharya

Where did guru [Shukracharya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shukra) live? Did he live in India or in some other country?

Comment: Just curious to know what made you conclude he lived in some other country?

Comment: @Just_Do_It see this video https://youtu.be/WPR1TZmjR7k

Comment: BTW Shukracharya hasn't died :P .. he is still there.

Comment: ...and how has youtube become a scriptural reference??

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda In answers we need to add scriptural reference. For questions it is not needed.

Comment: @Rickross thanks of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shukracharya ‘is’ the guru of the Daityas and Danavas. He is the planet Venus, among the nine planets in jyotisha and ‘lives’ in his own Loka which is described below.

As per the Puranas, the world of Shukracharya lies beyond that of Budha. It is about seven hundred thousand yojanas from the earth.

> O descendant of Kura, the Sun’s disc is a hundred thousand Yojanas from the earth (verse 1a). Beyond the abode of the Sun is the disc of the Moon. It is stationed a hundred thousand Yojanas (from the Sun) (Verse 23a). A hundred thousand Yojanas from the Moon high above shines the entire stellar zone (Verse 25a). Budha (Mercury) is two hundred thousand Yojanas above the stellar zone (verse 26b). **Uśanas (Shukracharya) is said to be stationed two hundred thousand Yojanas beyond Budha.**
> -*Chapter 38, Kaumārikā-khaṇḍa, Skanda Purāṇa*

As I state in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46011/20129) there is a story of a Brahmin named Sivasarman who is being taken through the upper worlds in the same order as aforementioned, right upto the the abode of Lord Vishnu. They reach the world of Shukracharya after they cross that of Budha which the Vishnudutas explain as follows:

> O Śivaśarman of great intellect, this is the wonderful world of Śukra. **Kavi, the preceptor of Dānavas and Daityas stays here.**
> -*Verse 1, Kāśī khaṇḍa Pūrvārdha, Skanda Purāṇa*

Thus to the above will make it clear that the Shukracharya lives in his own Loka situated about seven hundred thousand yojanas away from earth.

Comment: How much is seven hundred thousand yojanas in kilometers. Or 1 yojanas in km

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @DarkKnight thanks for accepting :D. 1 yojana = 12-14 km approx. Take 12.5 or so. So 7,00,000 would be 12.5 x 7,00,000 = 87,50,000 km. modern science says otherwise so :(