# In which lokas are the Apsaras born and which other lokas do they go on to inhabit?

Tags: sects, lokas, apsaras

Which are the exact lokas inhabited by the Apsaras according to different sampradayas?

Edit: Which lokas are the ones where Apsaras are born in the first place?

Comment: They live with the gandharvas in gandharva loka, which is in the lower part of swarga.

Comment: @Archit Based on the 2 comments and 1 answer so far I think we can safely say the relevant texts differ in their opinions and different sampradayas rank the relevant texts differently. Hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The Original Loka of the Apsaras

Apsaras are originally residents of a sub Loka named **Apsara Loka**, of the bigger Bhuvarloka. (Refer: [How many lokas are there?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39887/20129))

The region above the earth and below the sun, known as Bhuvarloka is inhabited by many different kind of celestial races like Siddhas, Gandharvas, etc. This region is described as:

> **The region that extends from the earth to the sun**, in which the Siddhas, etc (and other celestial beings) move, **is called Bhuvarloka**, which also I have described
> -*Vishnu Purāṇa 2.7.17*

A story of the ascent of a Brahmin named Sivasarman through higher lokas is found in the Skanda Purāṇa where his journey after death is described fairly in detail. As per this, while the attendants of Bhagwan Vishnu were taking the Brahmin from earth, through all the lokas, soon after Gandharva Loka, they encountered Apsara Loka before they reached the sun.

> **Hearing the origin of the Apsarāloka**, in this manner the eminent Brāhmaṇa reached the Solar World in a moment, travelling in an aerial chariot.
> -*Verse 28, Chapter 9, Kāśī khaṇḍa Pūrvārdha*

This shows us that the Apasaras are one of the categories of celestials (as mentioned in the Vishnu Purāṇa) who live between the region above the earth and below the sun known as Bhuvarloka and near Gandharva Loka, have their own sub-loka allotted to them by the name of Apsara Loka.

Thus to sum up, **Apsaras originally live in Apsara Loka of Bhuvarloka, between the earth and sun.**

---

#### Apsaras found in other Lokas

Often we come across a description where we see them frequenting other lokas or performing duties in other lokas as follows:

1. Apsaras described on Mount Kailasa (Refer: [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15645/20129))
2. Apsaras in Indra Loka as described [in the Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03167.htm) as well as the encounter of Arjuna with Urvashi there.
3. Apsaras again in Surya Loka in the abovementioned chapter of the Skanda Purāṇa (about verses 31-32)

However as stated above their original Loka is the Apsara Loka where as per the very same chapter of the Skanda Purāṇa about 60,000 apsaras live. (Verse 12)

In fact as one can see though the incident of Apsara Urvashi and Arjuna in Swarga Loka finds mention in Mahabharata, verse 7 of this chapter of the Skanda Purāṇa mentions her as one of the residents of Apsara Loka, the original abode of the Apsaras.

Such a difference must be understood by the fact that **Apsaras are originally the inhabitants of Bhuvarloka, however they do *frequent* other lokas**. This is similar to when say an Indian goes abroad for work, holidaying, he is not called a resident of that country or even if he permanently moves there, his Indian relatives back home do not become residents of that Loka or multiple lokas (just by few Apsras moving about, other Apsaras don’t become residents of Swarga, Manidvipa, Kailasa) . His origin lies in India and he will be called an Indian only. In the same way Apsaras going for work (to serve in Indra’s Loka) will still be Apsaras (Indians) only and their origin will lie in Apsara Loka (India).

Comment: Are Apsaras the only inhabitants of Apsarāloka?

Comment: @chhatra yes and no. Among celestials only apsaras. But women from earth who die and meet a specific criteria too become Apsaras in apsara Loka. It’s there in the same chapter of Skanda Purāṇa. Do you want me to add that? Or do you want to update your question and me to answer that?

Comment: @chhatra did you upvote that comment? If you did, which of the other two options would you likE?

Comment: That wasn't me. Who are these celestials you speak of?

Comment: @chhatra Celestials mean different species like apsaras, gandharvas, devatas, pitars, Yaksha, kinnara, siddha, vidyadhara, charana, Rakshasa, daitya, danava, pishacha etc. And of course apsara

Comment: Are these celestials born of celestial parents? Specifically, is an Apsara born from the union of an Apsara and a Gandharva?

Comment: @chhatra apsaras are born from the union of Kashyapa Rishi and Daksha’s daughter, Muni as per the Brahmanda Purāṇa 3.7.1. Supported by the Matsya Purāṇa 6.45, Srimad Bhagavatam 6.6.27 and uninterpolated Northern Recension of Valmiki Ramayana Sarga 19. The Upanishad is merely mentioning that they serve in Brahmaloka. That way common interpretation shows them in Deva Loka too but that doesn’t mean their origin is from there. There’s a difference. All these creatures are also described in other places too doesn’t mean they’re from there.

Comment: @chhatra for example see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/how-is-mount-kailash-the-abode-of-lord-shiva-described-in-hindu-scriptures) describing mount Kailasa. Apsaras serve here too with siddha and gandharva (as mentioned in my ans they both have a separate Loka in Bhuvarloka). See Devi Bhagavatam, Devi is described served by all creatures including famous apsaras. Does that mean they don’t have their own Loka? No. They all are originally from their own Loka only they move about or some live elsewhere for some time. For eg. If you go for a holiday, does your

Comment: Does your residence change? No. You’re originally from where you live. You either went temporarily or migrated there permanently, but you’re originally from your home town. A statement saying I saw chhatra serving in Bhutan. Doesn’t mean his home/ origin etc is from Bhutan. Probably he’s on holiday? Temporary job? Permanently migrated there. But other people similar to chhatra live where they originally are from. Just because chhatra went somewhere doesn’t mean they’re from multiple places.

Comment: Similarly Apsara Loka and other lokas too (not only apsaras it applies to other like gandharva and siddha and all). If some went for seeking something else doesn’t mean they’re from there. They would be temporarily or permanently there and the Generalisation is only for apsara Loka. Anyway skanda purana describes all main apsaras living in apsara Loka only and about 60,000 others

Comment: Thank you. This is also the point I had been trying to meld both answers into. Please consider including a precis of this explanation in your answer. That would also be in keeping with the edited question.

Comment: @chhatra cool done. Tried to keep it very brief since you’ve understood what I was trying to say in the comments. Thanks :)

Comment: Please excuse the long discussion. I just wish to address the other branch you had mentioned before I accept your otherwise eminent answer. You mentioned "women from earth who die and meet a specific criteria too become Apsaras in apsara Loka."  Do these beings have a significantly lesser lifespan or some other defect to be classified as not-quite-apsaras? Are they "born" in Apsaraloka? If not, how do they appear there?

Comment: @chhatra Okay thanks:) So it isn’t mentioned but I’m saying after death specifically. The Purana says that (1) a lady who breaks the vow of celibacy many times while observing a monthly fast many, so they come to apsara Loka to fulfil all desires. (2) after performing vrata they indulge in adultery (3) if an unknown man comes and they enjoy it wrongly considering him to be the husband (4) a specific vrata to become an apsara where you have to donate gifts to a Brahmin couple (5) with another man when husband is away (6) deva mated with 1lady and she meditated on that incident she became apsara

Comment: The one who did the vrata of donation to a Brahmin couple would stay for one kalpa in apsara Loka. Others the duration isn’t described so I don’t know. Thanks for accepting the answer in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

> [(**Kausitaki Upanishad 1.3**)](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/kausitaki1.asp) : He going by the path by which the immortal gods travel reaches the world of Agni (fire), then to the world of Vayu (air), then to the world of Varuna, then to the world of Aditya (sun), then to the world of Indra, then to the world of Prajapati, **then to the world of Brahma**. **In this world of Brahma, verily, is the** lake Ara, points of time called Yestiha, the river Viraja, the tree Ilya, the city Salajya, the court of Aparajita, the door keepers Indra and Prajapati, the hall Vibhu, the throne Vicaksana, the couch Amitaujas, the beloved Manasi and her twin Caksusi weaving the worlds with flowers, Ambas (mothers), Ambavayis (nurses), **Apsaras (celestial beauties)**, and the rivers called Ambayas. To this world comes the knower of this. To him Brahma says, "Welcome, you have my glory and you have reached the ageless river Viraja and you will never age."

Based on this verse from Kausitaki Upanishad we can say that Apsaras lived in Brahma-loka.

Comment: @user22556 Would that then make them more meritorious beings than the residents of  Indra loka?

Comment: @chhatra They reside in Brahma-loka. And not in Indra loka

Comment: @user22556 I understand that. Since Brahma-loka is higher than Indra loka it should follow that the beings there in general have higher "merit" (sattva guna?)  as compared to the residents of the latter. Do you agree with this inference?

Comment: @chhatra yes I agree

Comment: @user22556 In that case don't you find it strange then that they play the role of courtesans in Indra's court and may also be despatched at will by Indra to meddle with the aspirants of even lower worlds?

Comment: @chhatra the thing you are talking only happenedes in purans and not is the Vedas and upanishades. My answer is based on upanishad

Comment: @user22556 I am trying to incorporate the views from both answers so far. Am I correct in interpreting your answer in the sense that the Upanishad states that Apsaras reside in Brahmaloka but that it says nothing about whether they were born there?